# How do I get the current file's name in Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to send automated emails from the script of my spreadsheet. In the title of these, I want the file's name (In this example, "My Workbook", not "Sheet1") in the subject of the email. **How do I get the name of the file in/from which the script is running?**

[image]

I was hoping to get a [`File`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) object from a [`SpreadsheetApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) object, but it doesn't offer that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.getActive().getName();` would be pretty effective.

SpreadsheetApp doesn't refer to a specific spreadsheet, you need to specify one then get the name, hence the getActive().

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName()` gives me "My Workbook", you're sure you're not using `getActiveSheet()`?

Comment: Ah, sorry about the confusion. I'm still used to Excel terminology where each file is a workbook, and each sheet is a sheet.

Comment: This is not working for me. Whats the full script. I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get the name of the spreadsheet that you are running the script from use:

```
var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
```

Comment: No, I don't want the name of the spreadsheet. I already have that. I want the name of the file.

Comment: Have you tried the script that I wrote because it gives you the file name like you ask in the picture. In your case it will be 'My Workbook'. Spreadsheet is the whole file. 'Sheet1','Sheet2' and 'Sheet3' are called sheets, not spreadsheets.

Comment: Ah, sorry about the confusion. I'm still used to Excel terminology where each file is a workbook, and each sheet is a sheet.

Answer (score 3):

This solution works for all types of Google apps files (Docs, Sheets, Forms, ...)

You need to use DriveApp

The below code refers to Form, for instance:

```
const currentForm = FormApp.getActiveForm()
const formFile = DriveApp.getFileById(currentForm.getId())
const formName = formFile.getName()
```

Just get the document from the corresponding app, then use DriveApp to get the file by its ID, after that you will have the file name